# cmd.exe created with CreateProcess() doesn't read from WriteFile()

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a child process with CreateProcess(). an instance of cmd.exe. The first command is passed in the creation of the process and the second is passed through WriteFile(), after the process is created. The first job is done and the second isn't and I don't know the reason why. Please help

The code for creating the process is:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION _info;
char cmd[1024];
strcpy(cmd,"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /k echo 1");

    HANDLE _stdin_rd = NULL;
    HANDLE _stdin_wr = NULL;
    HANDLE _stdout_rd = NULL;
    HANDLE _stdout_wr = NULL;
    BOOL br;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    br = CreatePipe(&_stdin_rd, &_stdin_wr, &sa, 0);
    br = SetHandleInformation(_stdin_wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
    br = CreatePipe(&_stdout_rd, &_stdout_wr, &sa, 0);
    br = SetHandleInformation(_stdout_rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&_info, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdInput = _stdin_rd;
    si.hStdOutput = _stdout_wr;
    si.hStdError = _stdout_wr;
    br = CreateProcess(0, cmd,0,0,TRUE,CREATE_NO_WINDOW,0,0,&si,&_info);
    CloseHandle(_stdout_wr);
    CloseHandle(_stdin_rd);
    CloseHandle(_info.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(_info.hThread);
    printf("process created...\n");

    Sleep(320);
    printf("waited\n\n");
```

The code for communicating with the process is:

```
    char bufy[10240];
    char kom[1024];
    long unsigned int prt, ovs=0;
    for(int i=2;i<10;++i){
        if(!ReadFile(_stdout_rd,bufy+ovs,10240-ovs,&prt,0)){
            printf("   ERROR=%d\n",GetLastError());
            break;
        }
        ovs+=prt;
        printf("respond: ");
        bufy[ovs]=0;
        printf("%s\n",bufy);

        sprintf(kom,"/k echo %d",i);
        BOOL odgw = WriteFile(_stdin_wr,kom,strlen(kom),0,0);
        printf("sent(%s): %s\n",odgw?"TRUE":"FALSE",kom);
    }

return 0;
```

All I get on the output of my program is:

```
process created...
waited

respond: 1

D:\>
sent(TRUE): /k echo 2
```

Comment: You don't do any error checking. Start adding code for this.

Comment: If your code is compiled, then this is not C++.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I deleted error checking before uploading here because I wanted to make you people read more clearly. Anyway, from my output you can deduce that the code is stuck at ReadFile(). Where else do you need error checking?

Comment: @S.M. Which part of it isn't C++?

Comment: `char *cmd = "C:`...

Comment: @S.M. It is not allowed in ISO C++ standard, but g++ compiles it just fine

Comment: I'd suggest checking your code against the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ProcThread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).

Comment: this code is wrong by design. almost always both processes hang in this (both call readfile forever). use asynchronous i/o and read always, write at any time when need

Comment: @cnikbesku "*EDIT: I found the mistake*" - then feel free to [post that as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not as an edit.

Comment: `cmd[1024];` is nonsense and invalid syntax. At best some old trash C90 implicit int kicks in from your non-standard compiler and then you get an array of int. Are you actually using C++ and not C?

Comment: @Lundin Hi. Thanks for offending my code. My code comes between the other comments and your comment. When I made that edit in the code, after other comments and without recompiling it to test it, I made a mistake that you pointed out. I omitted the type. I will fix that overly-relevant part. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I found the mistake. Commands to be passed afterwards should not begin with `/k` and should end with `\n`. Then the program works. Also, in the creation of the process, there may not be anything after `/k`, the program will still work.